# crosscompile mipsel from a beginner

Tags: cross-platform

I have installed the "mipsel tuxbox" compile suite for crosscompile
Host system is x86_64 slackware
destination is mipsel32bit "vuduo+"

For example,I want to compile a program, I use this script

```
make clean
export TOOLCHAIN=/opt/mipsel-tuxbox-linux-gnu
export PATH="$TOOLCHAIN/bin:$PATH"
export CC=/opt/mipsel-tuxbox-linux-gnu/mipsel-tuxbox-linux-gnu/bin/gcc
export RANLIB=/opt/mipsel-tuxbox-linux-gnu/mipsel-tuxbox-linux-gnu/bin/ranlib
make
```

Compile and executable is..x86_64!

If I use this line give me a lot of error about includes not found

```
make CC=/opt/mipsel-tuxbox-linux-gnu/mipsel-tuxbox-linux-gnu/bin/gcc STRIP=/opt/mipsel-tuxbox-linux-gnu/mipsel-tuxbox-linux-gnu/bin/strip CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/mipsel-tuxbox-linux-gnu/mipsel-tuxbox-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/linux/ -I/opt/mipsel-tuxbox-linux-gnu/mipsel-tuxbox-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/sys/"
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions found, a script like that compile fine

```
make clean
export TOOLCHAIN=/opt/mipsel-tuxbox-linux-gnu
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/mipsel-tuxbox-linux-gnu/libexec/gcc/mipsel-tuxbox-linux-gnu/4.8.1/:/opt/mipsel-tuxbox-linux-gnu/bin
export LDCFLAGS=/opt/mipsel-tuxbox-linux-gnu/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/mipsel-tuxbox-linux-gnu/lib
make CC=mipsel-tuxbox-linux-gnu-gcc LD=mipsel-tuxbox-linux-gnu-ld
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also take a look at http://code.vuplus.com/index.php?action=repo

These systems are based on https://github.com/openembedded which use the https://github.com/openembedded/bitbake build system.

Besides the original vu+ from above there are many others like

- https://github.com/OpenPLi
- https://github.com/oe-alliance
- https://www.vuplus-support.org/wbb4/vtisoftware/

that let you build and integrate simple applications to full blown system images with consistent dependencies.

Other options are

- to use gcc/llvm/etc. and make (https://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Toolchains).
- create a Go compiler with crossdev (https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Crossdev) or build and manage your software with crossdev.
- use RUST (https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install) with the mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu toolchain.
- build an Erlang-Runtime with https://github.com/joaohf/meta-erlang and the above mentioned OpenEmbedded build system, then use it directly on your Box.
- cross compile D with GDC or LDC (https://wiki.dlang.org/Compilers).